# Regex replace matched Group content?

Tags: regex

I have the regex :

```
(a+)(,)(b+)
```

which is anallyzing the string : `aaaa,bbb`

It is very important for me to keep the group `$1 , $2, $3.`

I need a Regex usage( **only** , no Js , c# etc)  which will giv me this :

```
kkkk,ppp
```

**flow :**

```
1) emit group1  , group2  , group3
2) keep the $2 group
3)replace the 'a' to 'k' ( as many as 'a'.count)
3)replace the 'b' to 'p' ( as many as 'b'.count)
```

### edit

I dont have problem to `string.replace(regexp/substr,newstring)` in Js

But I dont want any loops or someting like that.

Comment: Sorry can't do with regex only. You can do it with perl/preg_replace_callback but this is not "regex" only because both of those versions execute code in the replacement function.

Comment: @FailedDev I dont have problem to `string.replace(regexp/substr,newstring)` in Js

But I dont want any loops or someting like that.

Comment: You don't specify the language - check @Ed's answer for a simple perl way.

Comment: @Royi: For JavaScript using string.replace, I am afraid it can't be done under these restrictions.

Comment: @FailedDev http://regexr.com?2vd5f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
str.replace(
   new RegExp("([ab]+)", "g"),  
   // Here, we are passing in a nameless function as the parameter for
   // the "replace" argument of the String Replace method. It uses the $1
   // to refer to the grouping of a or b.
   function($1){
      if ($1.charAt(0) == "a"){
      // replace with k
      return( $1.replace(/./g, "k") );
      } else {
      // replace with p
      return( $1.replace(/./g, "p") );
      }
   }
)
```

Adjust it to your own needs.

Comment: this is what is needed : `"aaaa,bbb".replace(
   new RegExp("(a+)(,)(b+)", "g"),  
      function($1,$2,$3,$4){
     return ($2.replace(/a/gi,'k')+$3+$4.replace(/b/gi,'p'))
      
   }
)`

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions are a pattern matching mechanism. What you are asking for is pattern replacement. This is possible by additional language constructs that differ from language to language, but not by regex itself. As you expressly exclude any language specifics, there is no answer to your question.

**Edit:**

Ok, now you have edited your question and allow language specific solutions. See Ed's answer.

Comment: this is my testing enviroment. I wasn hopping to find the solution  there. with find and replace.